# Debian 8 +xdm + fluxbox error not login

Tags: xorg, fluxbox, xdm

I am trying to install fluxbox in debian 8 with xdm. Problem is when i try to login with my username it shows X "Can't connect display: :0. But when I tried as root is shows fluxbox correctly. I tried lightdm but facing same problem. After installing debian Installed "sudo" as root then change my user as root. Then I instead xorg + fluxbox + xdm. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Why everything ok with root and not login with my username?

Answer (score 1):

It might be a file permissions problem.

Please verify that the `~/.Xauthority` file in your home directory is owned by your username, is up to date, and not accessible by anyone else:

```
$ ls -l $HOME/.Xauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username size date_of_your_last_login_attempt
```

Also verify that the Unix socket `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0` is accessible to your username (it should be owned by root but accessible to everyone):

```
$ ls -ld /tmp /tmp/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
drwxrwxrwt <some number> root root ... /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root ... /tmp/.X11-unix
srwxrwxrwx 1 root root ... /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

Also check the log files:

- `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, the X server log
- `/var/log/xdm.log` (or similar... not sure of the exact name)
- `~/.xsession-errors` file in your home directory, if it exists

One of them might contain a more detailed error message, that might give you more clues about what is going wrong.

Also, note that Debian 8 is out of regular Debian support and only supported by the Long Term Support team. [The LTS for Debian 8 is scheduled to end at the end of June 2020.](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS)